# Laravel not displaying whole content in blade.php

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

One of my Laravel blade.php files is used to view the data of my database. In this file I want to create a button. I code for it. But the button is not being displayed. It only shows the data from the database. Why is this happening?

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/app.css">

    <div class="container">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
            download pdf
        </button>
    </div>    

    @foreach($users as  $user){
        echo $user->name;}
    @endforeach
@endsection
```

Answer (score 2):

`@foreach` method has no brackets in blade. And change echo to `{{ }}` to print the values. Change to:

```
@foreach($users as  $user)
    {{$user->name}}
@endforeach
```

Comment: sorry i want to create a button of that blade file.but that button not view in the page.

Comment: Add your layouts/app to the question, then I can look if there is any problem with it.